# PHP: magic method executed each time a method is called

Tags: php, oop, magic-methods

Is there a magic method in PHP which is called each time another method is called? the __callStatic() and __call() magic methods seem to work only when the method doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. What you're asking for is called ["advice"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advice_(programming)) or [aspect oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming). I believe there are some experimental extensions to allow this in PHP, but nothing you'd want to use in production.

What you can do, is create a wrapper, that delegates all calls via `__call`. E.g.:

```
class Foo {
  function bar() {
    echo "Foo::bar\n";
  }
}
class AdviceWrapper {
  protected $subject;
  function __construct($subject) {
    $this->subject = $subject;
  }
  function __call($name, $args) {
    echo "Before $name\n";
    $result = call_user_func_array(array($this->subject, $name), $args);
    echo "After $name\n";
    return $result;
  }
}
$foo = new AdviceWrapper(new Foo());
$foo->bar();
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738282/are-there-any-working-aspect-oriented-php-libraries

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need this? You could just make a method and call it in each method you have in the beginning.

Edit:
What you search for is something like aspect-oriented programming in php.
A quick search on google found this here:
http://code.google.com/p/apdt/

Maybe it helps.

Comment: Edited the post. Maybe it helps :)

Comment: thank you Kufi it seems that AOP is what I need, but for my small project I think the solution of troelskn is sufficient

Answer (score 0):

Can you rename your methods with a _ in front of them?  Then all calls will get routed through __call / __callStatic?